# How to install tensorflow on a offline computer

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install tensorflow on a machine with no internet access: the machine has Windows 7 and Python 3.6 Anaconda.

I tried different approaches but non of them worked.

This what  i did so far:

- install anaconda with python 3.6
- pip install tensorflow tensorflow-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_and64.whl

But when I try to import tensorflow i get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name google
```

I have read that I should install `protobuf-3.6.tar.gz` but I get the error  `:register_loader_type...`

So I installed `setuptools-3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

and I still get the same error

So my question is: **is there any way to install tensorflow on a offline computer or there is something that I did wrong?**

NOTE: I am admin on this offline machine

Comment: just download the .whl file

Answer (score 4):

`python3 -m pip download tensorflow` on a machine with internet with the same OS. You will download all the needed packages to the current directory. Move the files onto a USB, mount the USB on the device without internet, and then do `python3 -m pip install --no-index --find-links . tensorflow` in the directory with the copied `.whl` files.

Answer (score 2):

create anaconda conda virtul environment in some internet available system and install necessary package for your project and copy virtual environment to you system. put inside anaconda env, it works

Answer (score 1):

Requirements :- Bazel [Installation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html), python >=2.7 and numpy.

You can use [link](https://github.com/amutu/tensorflow-offline). Installtion steps are given. I am explaining in more briefly:-

1. clone repo:-
   `git clone https://github.com/amutu/tensorflow-offline.git`
2. Download [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases?after=v1.3.0-rc0) and [tensorflow third party](https://github.com/amutu/tensorflow_third_party/releases).(Note:-you have to download compatible version of tensorflow with tensorflow third party.)
3. unzip them. In terminal run:-
   `tf=/path/to/tensorflow/directory` and `tp=/path/to/tensorflow/third/party/directory`.(Note:- you can check path typing $tf and $tp on terminal.)
   Example:- `tp=/home/ai/Documents/vineet/test/tensorflow_third_party-1.2.1`
   `tf=/home/ai/Documents/vineet/test/tensorflow-1.2.1`
4. Run:- 
   `cd tensorflow-offline`
5. In tensorlfow offline run:-
   `./fix_offline_build.sh $tf $tp`.(Note: you may also need to download tensorflow-port donwload it from [here](https://github.com/amutu/tensorflow-port/tree/5237251cbfc9a7c10fe75f611939beb41c100aa7) in tensorflow-port directory)
6. Configure tensorflow using:- `cd $tf && ./configure`
7. Build it using :- `bazel --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --verbose_failures` and 
   `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package`

Comment: can you help me plz?

Comment: @Papom git is not Installed please install git

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using Spyder with Python 3.11.

You can go [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/), search for the package you want to install, in the left there is the Navigation section, click download files.

Below Built Distributions, download .whl files according to your Python version and platform type.

For example for Tensorflow, Python 3.11 and Windows:

tensorflow-2.13.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl

is the name of the package you have to install.

After downloading all packages that you want, you can install those via Console in Spyder.

```
pip install --no-deps "C:\tensorflow-2.13.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl"
```

Above command will install the package. (Change the directory according to folder that you put files.)

Install all the packages using above command by changing the package name.

--no-deps option is there to install packages without dependencies. Without it, you might not be able to install all one by one.

After installation, you can check it with below command:

```
pip list
```

However, there are several .whl packages you want to install to use tensorflow.

List it using below command:

```
pip show tensorflow
```

And be careful that tensorflow depencies might depend on other packages. You have to install them to.